# If an error occurs, how do i insert the incident in to the db using the following script?

Tags: php, duplicates, equals

If a duplicate id error occurs i want to record it into the db.  I am using this snippet below, how do i make room for it to insert the error information in the db?

Code:

```
 if ( $postedid === $storedid ) {
 require("error.php");
 die("");
 }else{ 
 echo("");
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply pass the MySQL Query into the `die();` function.

You would get the errors using

[mysqli.errno.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php) and [mysqli.error.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

DB QUERY -

```
INSERT INTO error (type, page) VALUES ('{mysqli_error($dbc)}','{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}')

<?php
if ( $postedid === $storedid ) {
 require("error.php");
    $type = mysqli_error($dbc); //Where $dbc is your connection resource. 
    $file = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
      $q = "INSERT INTO error (type, page) VALUES ('{$type}','{$file}')";

 die( $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) );}
 else{ 
    echo("");
 }

?>
```

Comment: so get rid of the echo and do script in quotes?

Comment: @AAA I'm not understanding you.

Comment: i want to be able to do an insert on error like: INSERT into error_table Error_type, Error_page etc..

Comment: thanks but i think you misunderstood, how do i place the query in the given snippet in the question?

Answer (score 2):

You have to insert it before you close the script ( die() ). You insert a db query to log the error.